# How many EBS drives I can mount on a single EC2 instance using Amazon Web Services ( AWS )?

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

How many individually functioning EBS drives ( non-raided ) can I connect to a single Amazon EC2 server running Linux CentOS?  I can't find a value in the EC2 or EBS manuals.  Are there any other drive limitations I should be aware of with EBS?

Comment: Remember, EBS goes out over the network, so it's limited to your 1Gbps or so.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042413/what-is-the-max-number-of-attached-volumes-per-amazon-ec2-instance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some people have been able to attach 40 EBS devices to the same instance using RAID (see http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-ebs-raid)

You could probably attach more than 40, but be aware of the device names limitations, since according to [EC2 documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html) these are the only devices available for external EBS drives on Linux instances running xvd drivers:

```
/dev/sd[f-p]
/dev/sd[f-p][1-6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The current device attachment limits are described at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html and for the currently most typical HVM instance types they include:

```
/dev/sd[a-z]
/dev/xvd[b-c][a-z]
```

Meaning the limit is way beyond what it was in 2012.